# Constraints Satisfaction for Perfect Matchings

Tags: constraint-satisfaction-problems

Consider the problem of finding a perfect matching for a graph $G$ as a constraint satisfaction
problem where the variables are the vertices and there is just one global constraint (which
does not depend on the edges of $G$):

My formulation of it is:

Variables: A random subset of $|V|/2$ nodes $V'$

Domain: $V \backslash V'$

Constraints: $Alldiff(val(v_1,v_2,...,v_{|V|/2}))$ for $v_i \in V'$ and $(v_i,val(v_i)) \in E$

Constraint solvers generally use a mixture of constraint propagation methods (e.g., k-consistency, generalised arc consistency) and search methods (e.g., backtracking search).
Does this formulation allow the solver to decide in all cases whether a given graph has a perfect matching simply by using some standard form of constraint propagation (i.e., without using any search)?

I think that it's false because if we consider the complete graph of |V| nodes, any form arc consistency won't necessarily reduce the search space, but I'm not sure.